# Editing size of form control on Maximise

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a form that has a DataGridView, and I want to know how to get the control to change size to fit the form on maximise.

I have tried docking and anchors, as well as a basic attempt at setting the size of the control on `this.Maximise()` but I can't get anything to work properly for me. However I could just be overstepping something obvious.

The control sits on the right hand side of the screen:

[image: Form Normal state]

And this is what it looks like maximised:

[image: Form Maximised State]

Can someone suggest a way to keep the GridView stretched to fit the screen? (I only need horizontal stretch)

Comment: anchors are your best bet. does it have MaxSize set by any chance?

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev No, I wasn't too sure about setting that. The main issue I want to avoid is what it will look like on different size screens. Eg. `MaxSize = 1000` might look ok on a smaller screen, but it won't stretch large enough for a bigger one. But does that work in reverse? Eg `MaxSize = 2000` will shrink down for a smaller screen?

Comment: if you want to anchors to work you should have the maxsize to 0. is the grid inside another contrainer or straight on the form?

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev also I tried setting the anchor to left/right (invalid property value) and top/right (which only locks it to the outside of the form)

Comment: it's on the form, not it's own container

Comment: your anchors need to be top/left/right and optionally bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set anchors of the grid to top/left/right and optionally bottom.

Comment: I knew it was something obvious haha. Didn't know you could set more than two values for anchors.